# Website running .NET 3.5 cannot use feature not part of ISO-2 specs

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq, .net-3.5

I am getting this error a lot:

> Feature '*{insert feature here}*' cannot be used because it is not part of the
>   ISO-2 C# language specification

I am working on a .NET 3.5 website that I've worked on on and off for about two years. I've never seen this error before my most recent around of updates. I'm using a decent amount of LINQ coding throughout and I get these errors related to much of the LINQ code. Based on what I've read it seems like even though I'm using .NET 3.5, for some reason it thinks I'm using 2.0. But I can't find anything that says how to fix it.

One example of a problem is that if I try to add a new item to the App_Code directory, I do not get the option to add a LINQ to SQL dbml file.

If anyone can shed some light on how exactly I would fix this, I would much appreciate it.

I was unable to locate an "Advanced" option under the build tab. I have a feeling it is probably because it is a web app. I looked through the web.config and found 2 parts that may be important. Most things referenced 3.5.0.0 or v3.5. The settings are consistent with older backups of the web.config from when there were no errors. By the way, only intellisense and things within VS2010 are giving me problems. The website is running error free.

I have completed a total uninstall and re-install of VS2010 and I'm still having the same issue. I fired up my old install of VS2008 and I am NOT having this issue there. However, I would MUCH prefer to use VS2010 on this project.

I opened the website in VS2010 on my work computer, and there are no errors reported. This is making me think that there is something on my laptop that is causing the problem. As I noted above, I completely reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 and I am still having the problem. What does this leave? I have only one extension installed in VS, and it's the same one at work and on my laptop. Also, I did not reinstall the extension after reinstalling VS, and the problem persists.

Both PC's run Win7 Ultimate. Have VS2008 and VS2010 installed. VS2010 has the same extension installed on both. On my laptop I have the full version of SQL Server 2008 installed, but only the Management Studio on my desktop (we have a server in the office). Would SS2008 have anything to do with it?

Comment: Maybe you can check the web.config and add or change the *targetFramework* attribute in the *compilation* section (see "Configuration Files" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398791.aspx)

Comment: @SimonMourier: Key quote from that link "In projects that target the .NET Framework 4 or later versions, the compilation element of the Web.config file contains a targetFramework attribute..." I'm targeting .NET 3.5 for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Skeet's answer is mostly correct. The location for the update is in the "Property Pages" which I got to by right-clicking on the name of the website, clicking Property Pages, the Build item, then target framework.

The extension I use, Solution Navigator, has it's own heading for the solution. Right-clicking on it DOES NOT give me the Property Pages option. By chance I right clicked on the title of the website under the solution heading and was presented with the Property Pages option. In there was the Build tab which contained the target framework option.

Once I finally found the target framework option, it was indeed set to .NET 2.0 for some reason. I changed it to 3.5, reloaded the solution, and now it works great.

Thanks a million Jon for your help and time working with me!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project properties, the Build tab, Advanced - that should allow you to set which version of C# you want to use. It should default to the latest version supported by the version of Visual Studio you're using, but it sounds like at some point you've switched it to ISO-2.

(That's certainly true for Windows projects and class libraries - there *may* be a different location in a web app. In particular, have a look in Web.config.)

If this has only started happening recently, I'd have a look through your source control history at changes to any configuration files. Also try creating a new project of the same type, and see if that has the same problem.

Comment: @jwatts1980: If it's *running* okay, it sounds like the execution-time config is fine. Did you look through source control for any config changes? Was it all working correctly before?

Comment: Ha ha! Source control. That would nice :] Seriously though, we don't have any source control on the website. All we have is a couple of full site backups the newest of which is 18 months old. For what it's worth, there are only a handful of differences between the 18 month old web.config and the new one. And none of them appear to be things that would matter. The sections I listed in my update are the same in the 2 files.

Comment: The other admin is in the Netherlands. I'll shoot him an email and see if he's been in the site in the last couple of months, and if he's made any changes.

Comment: My partner said that he has not made changes to the website, and the last time he was in there he did not see this error. Since I'm working with this over FTP in VS, is it possible that it's some kind of caching error? Or are there any other settings that would make Visual Studio think I am working with another language specification?

Comment: Jon, after getting into work today, I am looking for the Project Properties > Build Tab > Advanced on a Windows application I am working on. And I can't find it. I have clicked on every properties option I can, and have not yet seen a Build tab or Build anything. How do I get to that?

Comment: Ok, I think I finally found it under My Project > Compile > Advanced Compile Options > Target Framework. (My work application is in VB if it matters.)

Comment: Ok. My work environment is VB/Windows applications, and my consulting environment is C#/Web apps. I appreciate your time and you help, Jon! I assume if you had any other options, you would offer them. I will leave the question open to see if someone can shed anymore light on this, and next chance I get, I'll try creating a new project to see if the error happens there as well.

Comment: @jwatts1980: It's only just struck me that it's very strange for it to be complaining about the C# compiler version if this is actually a VB project. It's not clear what you mean about the difference between your "work environment" and your "consulting environment" - I don't understand why you'd be looking in your VB/Windows project if it's the web project which is causing problems.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I only meant that I am less familiar with some of the project configuration options/locations for C# projects and web projects. The grand majority of my time is spent working with VB desktop apps. For this problem, I am working with a C# .NET 3.5 web project. The website runs with no issues, but Visual Studio 2010 thinks that I've got all kinds of syntax errors because of this ISO-2 standards issue. It appears to be not only affecting Intellisense but also what kinds of templates I can use when I attempt to add a new file to the project.

Comment: Further, in a previous comment, I mentioned that I was unable to find the setting you described. Then I realized later that I was looking for the setting on my work machine while I was editing a VB desktop solution.

Comment: @jwatts1980: Right - so have you now looked for the setting within the *actual* project? It does sound like something is oddly screwed up - if you create a new project, do you have the same problems? Possibly create a new one and diff the project/config files...

Comment: I opened the website from VS2010 at work today, and there are no errors reported. See update #3 in my question for more details.

Comment: I figured it out. Your suggestion was 90% right, I just couldn't find the right place to go. I rewarded the bounty (meager as it is compared to your rep!) to you, and I added my own answer for the exact solution. Thank you so much for you help!